# Normalize equation in NDSolve?

Tags: functions, function-construction, syntax

I have numerically solved and plotted the solution to the Mathieu equation using NDSolve successfully, as below:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
a = 0.5;
b = 0.1;
w0 = 2.0;
T = 2 Pi/w0;

f[t_] := f[t] = y''[t] + (a + b  Cos[t]) y[t] == 0

s = NDSolve[{f[t], y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, {t, 0, 1}]

Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. s], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

But now I wish the normalize the period so I can plot from `t=0 -> t=1` and get 1 full period. I can do this by hand, but how do I do this inside of the `NDSolve` function?

Comment: What are `w0` and `T`? You don't seem to be using them ...

Comment: *Mathematica* knows `MathieuC`.

Comment: w0 is the normal frequency of the periodic function, in this case Cosine. T would be the normalization factor, but if I multiply the Cos function by T, my plot doesn't normalize as I expected. In fact, nothing changes.

Comment: @Kuba Yes, I know, but I will use this code to check more complex DE's with periodic coefficients later so I'd like to make it general instead of using MathieuC.

Comment: I see a difference with and without the factor `T`.  Look at the scale on the vertical axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are after? Using WhenEvent to find the extrema..

```
 s = Reap[ 
      NDSolve[{y''[t] + (a + b Cos[t]) y[t] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0, 
         WhenEvent[ y'[t] == 0 && y[t] > 0 , Sow[{ t, y[t]}]]}, 
        y, {t, 0, 50}] ]
 Show[
   Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. s[[1]]], {t, 0, 50 }, PlotRange -> All],
      ListPlot[s[[2, 1]], PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[.02]}]
       ]
```

[image]

The solution isn't exactly periodic, or it has a long period..so its not exactly clear what you mean to normalize to the period.

If I put

```
WhenEvent[ y'[t] == 0 && Abs[y[t] - 1] < .001 , Sow[{ t, y[t]}]]
```

we find "period" of ~ 170 where the solution returns to a good approximaiton to `y=1,y'=0`